# WPF Auto-Resize Window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I'm working on a WPF application in VB.net

I am struggling with making the Window/controls automatically resize.

My XAML structure right now:

- ScrollViewer

  - ViewBox

    - Grid

      - Various controls (Label, TextBox, etc) ...
      - **DataGrid**
      - Button

The **DataGrid** is the main control that I'm confused about. It is bound to a DataTable in my VB.net code. The DataTable changes dynamically (i.e. rows can be added and removed). In doing so, I'd like for the **DataGrid** to be able to change size too, in order to account for the new rows (or removed rows).

At the moment, I am hard-coding a change in height for the DataGrid, Grid, ViewBox, and Window itself. I am also forced to move the Button after the DataGrid up/down by 1 row each time a row is added/removed from the DataTable (also hard-coded)

Is there a way this can be done automatically? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Remove ScrollViewer and ViewBox use only grid.**

ScrollViewer practically give you infinite area to place controls so no resize is happened.

ViewBox allow you to zoom controls. You probably don't need this one if you don't want make huge buttons.

Grid allow you place controls that they resize:
https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/

You can create complex layouts like this:
[WPF Grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432654/wpf-grid-layout)

Your datagrid already contain ScrollViewer so can toggle scrollbar visibility, and you can get scrollbars when needed.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
</DataGrid>
```